# Import file from another folder

Tags: external-files, import, folders

Hi I need to import a file.tex (I cannot move it from this folder) file from a different folder of the main file.

is it possible? how i should do?

Comment: `\input{relative/path/to/the/other/folder/file.tex}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: It doesn't work! I'm using 
\input{C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/TESA_economics/SES/pluto.tex}
The error is:
!Missing $ inserted.
<inserted tex>
$
\input{C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/TESA_economics/SES/pluto.tex}

Have you some idea?

Comment: Your problem is the space in your user name and also try to avoid special characters such as `_` in your file or folder names. Try with a relative path. For example if your main file is in the folder `TESA_economics`: `\input{./SES/pluto.tex} `

Comment: @samcarter underscores in file names are not special and not a problem.

Comment: You should better use relative pathes instead of absolute pathes, beside this the command should work unless `Myname` contains something problematic. From you error message it is not possible to say if the input failed or if the error is from something *inside* the file,

Comment: Is it possible that the error coming from the fact that "My name" contain a space? I'm not able to manage the relative path, have you some handbook or something?

Comment: google. There are everywhere tutorials for relative pathes. But you can only use them, if both files are in the same partition. Then you can use `../` for "up one folder". So a file in a parallel folder is in `../otherfolder/file.tex`.

Comment: In the relative path: Place a backslash before any space or underscore. Does that help?

Comment: @Marc Can you tell us the full path to your main file?

Comment: My main file is in: "C:\Users\Marco Scelzo\Desktop\TESA_economics\SES\graph\Box_plot eps1" instead the file that i'm trying to include is two folder earlier in: "C:\Users\Marco Scelzo\Desktop\TESA_economics\SES"

@RobtAll I have tried with the backslash before underscore and space but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

First, use `\usepackage{import}`. Then, use `\import{Path}{File.tex}`. Inside the first braces, use the file path, eg. `/Folder/OtherFolder/.../PackageFolder/`. In the second one, put the file name(including extensions like `.tex`).

For example, if the file's relative path is `/Parts/Project/file.tex`, this is the MWE you would use.

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\usepackage{import}
...
\begin{document}
    ...
    \import{/Parts/Project/}{file.tex}
    ...
\end{document}
```

*Note: I'm not sure if you use file extension. Try experimenting!*

Comment: Does this answer work for you? If it doesn't, could you please explain why and how I could improve it?

Comment: Maybe do `../Parts/Project/`?